# Do typecasts use conditionals internally? (C#, C/C++)

Tags: c#, c++, optimization, conditional-statements, language-design

This question is most specific to C#, but it would be interesting to know about C/C++, too. Java has to use conditionals, I guess, given its dynamic typecasting / lack of compile-time generics.

Branching is best avoided where branchless logic may be used, for performance reasons. So it would be interesting to know, for potential avoidance in critical sections.

Comment: Um, wouldn't it make more sense to ask what is done overall, before asking whether it branches? Not to mention that your premise is questionable, and you'd be better off **measuring** performance for the specific case you care about.

Comment: I'm referring to the premise in the question: That a branchless implementation is preferable, for performance reasons. Please don't get the "um" wrong, I am simply confused as to why would you ask about this particular detail rather than about the implementation of casts as a whole. Knowing whether something branches tells very little about how it performs, just like knowing that something has wheels doesn't tell you much about its movement speed. If you [explained your actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), answers are more likely to actually solve your problem.

Comment: @delnan I do not need to explain any problem. I am asking a simple, generalised question, and in return I expect a simple answer. Someone will give that answer, ultimately. Possibly someone who has experience of language / compiler design. I will also note here, as a top 10 user on one of the other SO programming sites, that more questions should be less verbose. So to my mind, this is a model question.

Comment: For C++: `static_cast`, `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` can be resolved at compile time. No need to do branching, although there might be a need to call functions, if the respective constructors / casting operators can't be inlined. Apart from that, I think that there are little guarantees about how casting between native types is implemented. So I would say that the exact costs of type casts may depend on the specific compiler (version), architecture and more. Whether casting pays off also depends on vectorization capabilities and other stuff. Question is too generic (for C++) IMHO.

Comment: In C# a lot of different kinds of cast actually have the same syntax, but it really matters for the implementation which kind of cast it really is. Also the `checked`-mode can be important, when casting between primitive types.

Comment: "lack of compile-time generics": did you mean "lack of run-time generics"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When downcasting, the answer is certainly yes, since it requires a walk down a tree with multiple choices at every level.

When upcasting, it depends on how the iteration is done to walk up the type tree. Under most circumstances the answer would probably be yes, but some optimisations on the tree (specifically, its layout in memory) might allow the walk-up to be a branchless operation.

Answer (score 0):

> This question is most specific to C#

No it isn't. The entire topic is deliberately left out of the specification of both both C# and CIL. The specifications has nothing to say on the subject.

You are asking about a implementation detail of a just-in-time compiler.

Now that this have been cleared up, I may add that I have read technical articles over years from Microsoft on how to analyze CIL to find both simple and complex cases that would allow to optimize casts. However, Microsoft don't go into details when they talk about the actual implementation their jitter.

So the best you can do is to code some test in a manner that the optimizer will compile it, and look at the machine code generated when not using a debugger.

Comment: Apparently some people just like sabotage questions. I guess it was the person I told off for their silly comments on my question.